# azure cli list nic attached to VM

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am working on bash shell. I need az cli or unix script to find out NIC name attached to particular VM. I know VM name and VM Resource Group Name and my Target is to findout out which NIC is attached to this VM and which resouce group this NIC belongs to?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this line of azure cli code:

Step 1: Define a variable, like `a`. **Note that** there is **no whiteSpace** around the chars `=` :

```
a="$(az vm nic list --resource-group "your_resource_group" --vm-name "your_vm_name" --query "[].{id:id}" --output tsv)"
```

[image]

Step 2: Just get the nic name and it's resource group:

```
az vm nic show -g "your_resource_group" --vm-name "your_vm_name" --nic $a --query "{name:name,resourceGroup:resourceGroup}" --output table
```

[image]

Step 3: If you want get all the information of nic, please use the code below:

```
az vm nic show -g "your_resource_group" --vm-name "your_vm_name" --nic $a
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

az vm nic list --resource-group
               --vm-name
               [--subscription]

This will list all nics on a vm.

eg. az vm nic list -g MyResourceGroup --vm-name MyVm

Comment: No this does not provide desired output
                                
#az vm nic list -g rg-csc-entsys-dev-sap --vm-name RHELREPOCLIENT03
                                                                                                              
Primary    ResourceGroup
---------  ---------------------
True       rg-csc-entsys-dev-sap

Comment: i have VM name and Its Resource Group . i want detaila of NIC attached to VM ..like NIC name and its reaource group.