# Is there a way to List all the VM's from the Application Security Group

Tags: azure, networking, application-security-group

As we know we can group the Vm's into a single App Security Group and use them as a Single Entity for the NSG rules.

I'm searching a way to find what are all the VM's thats associated to my security group.

From the [azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/asg?view=azure-cli-latest) its showing the properties of App Security Group, but not the Association of VM's it does.

Is there a way to get/list all the VM's for a given Application Security Group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at this from the NIC.  If you do a `az network nic list` you can see the ASG's assigned to a NIC.  You can look at this answer on how to list out the nic's associated with a VM.

[azure cli list nic attached to VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55051428/azure-cli-list-nic-attached-to-vm)

Answer (score 1):

Ken provided the exact path to the solution. All I need to do is to to find the relevant queries(jmespath) in Azure CLI . I used the below query to get the desired solution for my use-case

```
az network nic list --query "[].[ipConfigurations[].applicationSecurityGroups[? contains(id,``<replace-your-asg-name>``)],virtualMachine]"
```

Ofcourse the above query needs some work as it will still show all VM list . May be it will give some lead to others to enhance it more precise for their needs.